# How to make awk execute (i.e. re-execute) a system command (e.g. date) each time a line of input piped from tail -f is processed

Tags: date, awk, command, tail, prepend

I'm trying to prepend the current time to a few columns pulled from each line of a growing text file, and print to the screen.

```
tail -f dumpfile.txt|awk '{ "date +%T"|getline curtime;print curtime, $2, $7 }'
```

A sample input line from the file would be:

```
N 7056 65433 flags 0dbc a000 OK 0
```

Above command prints each line from tail, however it executes `date` just once, time that the command line is launched:

```
Desired             Actual
13:10:05 7050 OK    13:10:04 7050 OK
13:10:05 7051 OK    13:10:04 7051 OK
13:10:06 7052 OK    13:10:04 7052 OK
13:10:06 7053 OK    13:10:04 7053 OK
13:10:07 7054 OK    13:10:04 7054 OK
13:10:07 7055 OK    13:10:04 7055 OK
13:10:08 7056 OK    13:10:04 7056 OK
```

How can I rewrite this so that the date command is executed each time a new line comes in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `getline` exhausts `date`'s output (as it's just a single line), subsequent calls to `getline` fail and leave `curtime` unchanged. You need to close the file descriptor associated with `date +%T` every time you read from it, e.g:

```
tail -f dumpfile.txt | awk 'BEGIN{cmd="date +%T"} {cmd|getline curtime; print curtime,$2,$7; close(cmd)}'
```

Comment: Works! Thank you for explaining why it didn't work, as well as for providing the fix.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
| awk '{print strftime("%H:%M:%S", systime()), $2, $7}'
```

Output (example):

```
16:58:35 7056 OK
```

---

See: [9.1.5 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Comment: Cyrus, excellent and elegant solution.  Thanks for the help.  I accepted oguz's answer because I indeed wanted to know generically how to make sure "command"|getline will work properly.  In the special case of prepending specifically time of day vs some other thing, your answer is best.